# what method should I use to preprocess complex dataset in scikit learn?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, dataset, scikit-learn

I'm very new to the stack community and a beginner in data processing. I want to create a prediction model using SVM and DT. I want to create a model based on my dataset but unfortunately my dataset is a little bit complex. this is an example of my dataset:

```
Feature1     Feature2            Feature3   Label
[1,3,9,5]    [612,322,244,466]   [c,s,i,p]  1
[89,23,1,4]  [700,313,444,212]   [c,s,s,i]  -1
...........................................
[103,6,1,2]  [111,232,655,432]   [s,c,s,p]  1
```

I try to use this dataset but SVM or DT cannot create a model and I get an error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "['1','3','5','9']"
```

Is there any method i can use to convert my dataset so it can be used to build a prediction model with SVM and DT?

Comment: You should treat each 'sub-feature' as a new feature. Therefore, given the above dataset, you would have 12 features. Of course, you should find a way to convert the string features to numeric ones (look at one-hot encoding). Or, if the order of the letters is important, you could create a synthetic feature like 'csip' and then use OHE.

Comment: It looks like you need to break each of your features in to subfeatures as @Stergios says. Also might want to consider whether your features are categorical or not. Feature 3 looks particularly nasty, encapsulating orders of distinct objects as meaningful features can be tricky.

Comment: @Stergios yeah i can try that but is it okay if the features are categorical (even though the values are in integer)? and also the order of the letters are important

Comment: @ncfirth yeah the features are categorical value even though they're integers. what should I do to make the features are better (so there wont be an overfitting case)?

Comment: If the features are categorical (even though the values are in integer), you should treat them as categorical. Basically, it depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want to run a Decision Tree and be able to understand it, you should use OHE for all categorical features. Else, if you only care about prediction accuracy, try using the features with and without OHE and see what gives you better results. As for the order of the letters, try either using them as separate features or create a new synthetic feature (e.g. 'csip') and use OHE on it. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Stergios okay thank you so much for the explanations, i will try it immediately and see how it works